# Can i2cdump/i2cget be used in a C executable?

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu, system, i2c

I have a script that creates a file, and generates a timestamp from the system's time, and names the file by that timestamp.

```
// Creating file name. Time stamp included. File will be sent to USB.
    
    FILE * fp;
    
    time_t rawtime;             // Generating time stamp
    char buffer[255];
    time(&rawtime);
    sprintf(buffer, "/mnt/usb/DAT_%s.txt", ctime(&rawtime));
```

However, I'd like to generate the time stamp from an RTC via I2C. From the terminal, I can easily read the time from the RTC:

```
$ i2cdump -y -r 0-0xF 1 0x68 b
     0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f    0123456789abcdef
00: 51 51 21 01 14 01 17 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 1c 88    QQ!????.......??
```

Where each register corresponds to

- 00h-06h: seconds, minutes, hours, day-of-week, date, month, year (all in BCD)

So the above reads as 21:51:55 Saturday 01/14/2017 (I hope).

For time stamping purposes, printing the registry values (unformatted) is enough. So can I used i2cdump in this script? If so, how should it be implemented? I am fairly new to C, so any advice aimed at noobs is appreciated!

Comment: You can simply run `i2cdump` and read its output through a pipe, `man popen`.

Answer (score 0):

You can read the output of a utility like `i2cdump` using pipes. For example:

```
FILE *f = popen ("i2cdump", "r");
// read from f until end of file
pclose (f);
```

However, it's not all that difficult to read from the I2C bus directly, using the kernel's built-in driver. In outline:

```
#include <fcntl.h>   
#include <linux/i2c-dev.h>
#include <linux/i2c.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>

int f = open ("/dev/i2c-0", O_RDONLY); // Or whatever your device is
ioctl (f, I2C_SLAVE, address);
read (....);
close (f);
```

There's a bit more to it, of course, but that's the gist. Implementing the I2C operation in code is not all that difficult, removes the dependency on an external utility, and will be slightly faster in operation.

Comment: Why?! There is `libi2c` for that. -1.

Comment: Why introduce another dependency into your application, which you may well have to build from source for an embedded platform, and which you'll have to learn how to use, to do a job that's almost trivially easy to do in code?

Comment: Why to have an OS if you can run anything on bare metal?